# Meteor worker thread based on collection state

Tags: meteor

Suppose I have a collection called `data` with following structure.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    status: "new",
    moreData: ""
}
```

Is there a way to create worker thread in Meteor which listens to `data` collection all the time without failing. When a new data is inserted into collection `data` with status `new` it picks up the data, processes it and when done it updates data and status to `completed`

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection-hooks package to archive this. You want to run some code `before.insert` to process it. I'm assuming that you are using Meteor as data entry point with mini-mongo. If you've a REST API for this, you manually run your code to archive this.

Regarding MattK answer,
when you use `observeChanges` on the server, outside of the scope of publications, you're wasting memory because you're fetching the last X records from the database. This approach works although it's not optimal.

Another possible issue about using `observeChanges` that I'm not sure about: I once built a realtime system to act upon a mongodb insert. I used tailored cursors with a capped collection and It was able to catch all insert for my needs. I though about using observeChanges but I think there is the possible of missing some documents. If I fetch the last 10 documents and I inserted 20 in last second, I don't know if observeChanges will get all the 20 inserted documents, I've to run my own tests to check this potential issue.

Comment: Am inserting data via REST API. I don't wan't to process data at the time of insertion, as it takes time, it involves talking to 3rd party server. I wan't processing to as a demon/worker thread.

Comment: You can simply call the 3rd party server's REST API, you must use Meteor.wrapAsync in case the response must be valid to validate the insert. Check: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call

Answer (score -2):

Just spawn a `child_process` thread inside an `.observeChanges` `.added` callback.
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes